# Without Thread.sleep Webdriver IE will give “unable to find element” exception

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I’m a beginner and need help.  I have google everywhere and tried my best and still can’t find the answer to this IE 11 issue.  My script runs well in Firefox and Chrome but for some reason IE 11 32bit is giving me this error “Unable to find element…” If I add a “Thread sleep” before driver find Element
it runs but slowly.  I DO NOT want to add Thread sleep to every other line of my script, it will run slowly!  There MUST be something that I missed.  Looking for a solution to run this on IE 11 w/o this exception.  please help.

Below are some notes that I did already, what I’m using, my script, and my error.

1. What I googled
   “Webdriver IE unable to find element” and checked all links and still can’t find solution
2. Using Eclipse, writing my script in Java
3. Version:11.0.9600.17691
   Update Version:11.0.17 (KB3032359)
4. at this link---> code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver
   -Testing with IE 32bit.  I did both 32bit and 64 bit versions of the browser (IEDriverServer.exe)(64 bit runs really slow, but read somewhere it’s a bug, so I been testing with 32 bit)
   -I have done all the required configuration with IE 11. (set the protected mode settings for each zone to enable protected mode, set browser zoom level to 100%, set registry entry for 64 bit windows installations
5. Used webdriverwait and didn’t work. Example below.

   WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Parties"))).click();
6. [Went to microsoft and download the IE webdriver tool for IE 11
   (win 7 –KB2990999-x64.msu) and didn’t resolve the issue](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=44069)
7. What I found about IE.  Is this true?

   The IEDriverServer.exe starts up an HTTP server on your local machine. Your language bindings use an HTTP client to communicate with the server using a JSON-over-HTTP wire protocol. However, starting this HTTP server is not instantaneous; it takes a little time for the IEDriverServer.exe to initialize it and be ready to receive HTTP requests from the language binding clients. When you call "new InternetExplorerDriver()" from your Java code, the Java language bindings launch IEDriverServer.exe, but then has to wait for the HTTP server to be ready. It waits by polling the server with the HttpClient class until it receives a valid response. What you're seeing is the driver saying, "The IEDriverServer.exe's HTTP server isn't receiving connections yet, just letting you know."
8. My test script

   ```
   public void TestThread() throws Exception {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
   driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   driver.get(baseUrl);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '?p=n&sectid=38')]")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.name("login_email")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.name("login_email")).sendKeys("1000016");
   driver.findElement(By.name("login_password")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.name("login_password")).sendKeys("testing123");
   driver.findElement(By.id("setLogin")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Parties")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("d327_host1_FF")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Review Bookings")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("addNewBooking")).click();
   ```
9. My error

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
>   2.42.0.0 Listening on port 2619 FAILED: TestThread org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with link text == Parties (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 308 milliseconds

1. WebDriver Wait not working for me

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Parties"))).click();
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("d327_host1_FF"))).click();
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Review Bookings"))).click();
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("addNewBooking"))).click();
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("guests-booking-modal-element-2"))).sendKeys("Booking added at party order");
   ```
2. webdriverwait error

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
>   2.42.0.0
>   Listening on port 35252
>   FAILED: TestThread
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at firsttestngpackage.TestIEUnableToFindElement.TestThread(TestIEUnableToFindElement.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Could you provide HTML fragment you're testing? 
Also, WebDriverWait should work! May be you can try different selector (not linkText, but id or cssSelector)?

Comment: I dont see any explicit waits added in the code?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body><div class="csMainHeader"><div class="csFixedHeader"><div class="csMainNav"><div class="csInnerNav"><div class="nav"><ul><li class="navSect"><a href="http://test.com/open-parties">Parties</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></body>
</html>

Comment: @sap1ens i have added HTML frag.  can you give me an example of webdriverwait, bc it's not working for me :(  I don't have an ID or cssSelector to this element.  there is link and xpath:link, xpath:href, and xpath:position where I'm extracting from selenium IDE

Comment: @LittlePanda I have added using webdriverwait and getting the following error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with WebDriverWait for the findElement method  (if it cannot find the element, it cannot check for visibility).  This can be done using the implicit wait setting of the driver itself.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Just set that right after instantiating your driver, and it will wait for up to 30000 milliseconds (30 seconds) for the element to exist before throwing an exception when it cannot find an element with findElement.

It is worth noting that WebDriverWait is insanely useful.  Just not in this particular use-case.

Comment: You are awesome!  That did the trick.  I have this implicitly wait in my other scripts and thought this was useless because one point it took forever to finish my script so I changed the time 30000 to 5000 to do my script faster.  Never put implicit and IE together until now.  Can't believe I haven't see this on google.  Great job!  wish I can up vote your answer but don't have enough reputation!